# How to validate PATCH requests on large objects with Spring

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I can't seem to find a lot of information about this. I've read that `PUT` requests should be used for replacing an entire resource with an updated resource, and that `PATCH` requests should be used to update only the fields you want to change. But let's say I have a very large object with lots of nested fields and objects, and I want to update only specific fields in one of its nested objects rather than having to resubmit the entire thing (because it's just too large). I would have to create a `PATCH` endpoint. How would I go about validating such an endpoint in a Spring REST API? I can't get my head around how the endpoint would know which fields or nested fields it has received and how to validate them, and have it work for any possible field I could give it.

Comment: you will have to write the validation yourself, thats not something spring will do for you

Answer (score 1):

When a request comes into spring, it will cast it to an object for example.

```
 @PatchMapping("/customer/1")
 public void updateCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerPatch updateRequest) {
 }
```

Here we are casting the customer patch request to a `CustomerPatch` object.

With this, we can validate the object just as we would with any other object.

I personally use the `@Valid` annotation paired with hibernate validator.

so my spring controller would look like.

```
@PatchMapping("/customer/1")
public void updateCustomer(@RequestBody @Valid CustomerPatch updateRequest) {
}

public class CustomerPatch{
    @NotNull
    String cusotmerName;
}
```

Comment: But let's say my patch request is to update a nested field within an object contained within the Customer object. Something like customer.nestedObject.nestedField1. In that case, when it gets mapped to a CustomerPatch object, only the nestedField1 will have a value and everything else will presumably be null. How do I then know that everything else is null because it hasn't been provided with a value in the patch request, rather than being intentionally set to null?

Comment: Great question, as far as I know, that concept does not exist in java. Similar to undefined/null in javascript. 

Personally, when I use PUT and a field is null i will set it to null, when i use PATCH and a field is null i will skip it.